# Create a list of dict with VueJS

Tags: javascript, list, vue.js, dictionary

I have an HTML table where I took some values displayed in the table and other inputed by user and only for the row the checkbox is checked.
A row of my table looks like this:
[image: A row of my table looks like this]

Here is the code of my table:

```
<template>
<table id="Ref" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Nouvel ID</th>
      <th scope="col">Nouveau Type</th>
      <th scope="col">Nouvel URL</th>
      <th scope="col">Nouvelle date d'expiration</th>
      <th scope="col"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="row in rows">
      <td> <a :href="row.url" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">{{ row.id }}</a></td>
      <td> {{ row.typ }} </td>
      <td> <input v-model.trim="row.newID" type="text" placeholder="ID"> </td>
      <td> <input v-model.trim="row.newType" type="text" placeholder="Type"> </td>
      <td> <input v-model.trim="row.newURL" type="text" placeholder="URL"> </td>
      <td> <input v-model.trim="row.newExpDate" type="text" placeholder="Date d'expiration"> </td>
      <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;"> <input v-model="row.isSelected" type="checkbox"> </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</template>
```

My goal is to return a list of dict like this:

```
[{
    "id1": "newID1",
    "type1": "newType1",
    "url1": "newURL1",
    "exp1" "expDate1"
},
    {
    "id2": "newID2",
    "type2": "newType2",
    "url2": "newURL2",
    "exp2" "expDate2"
},
    {
    "id3": "newID3",
    "type3": "newType3",
    "url3": "newURL3",
    "exp3" "expDate3"
}]
```

I tried with `reduce` but it will only return me a dict, not a list.

```
   putInvalidsRef() {
      const selectedRef = this.rowsInvalidsRef.filter((ref) => ref.isSelected === true);
      const refsDicts = selectedRef.reduce((acc, item) => {
        acc[item.id] = item.newID || null;
        acc[item.typ] = item.newType || null;
        acc[item.url] = item.newURL || null;
        acc[item.exp] = item.newExpDate || null;
        return acc;
      }, {});
      console.log(refsDict);
      this.$http.admin.putInvalidsRef(refsDict)
        .then(getInvalidsRef);
    }
```

Sorry if the answer is trivial, I'm really new to frontend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `{}` use `[]` to return list:

```js
function putInvalidsRef() {
  const selectedRef = this.rowsInvalidsRef.filter((ref) => ref.isSelected === true);

  const refsDicts = selectedRef.reduce((acc, item) => {
    return [
      ...acc,
      {
        [item.id]: item.newID || null, // Be sure if here item has id and newID property
        [item.typ]: item.newType || null,
        [item.url]: item.newURL || null,
        [item.exp]: item.newExpDate || null
      }
    ]
  }, []);
  console.log(refsDicts);
  this.$http.admin.putInvalidsRef(refsDicts)
    .then(getInvalidsRef);
}
```